# RinSim inconsistent NullpointerException GraphSpatialRegistry in sim.start()

Tags: java, rinsim

We currently have a warehouse AGV problem running on RinSim.
Sometimes during execution we get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.GraphSpatialRegistry.getConnection(GraphSpatialRegistry.java:133)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.GraphRoadModelImpl.getConnection(GraphRoadModelImpl.java:478)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.ui.renderers.AGVRenderer$VehicleUI.update(AGVRenderer.java:294)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.ui.renderers.AGVRenderer.renderDynamic(AGVRenderer.java:98)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.ui.SimulationViewer.paintControl(SimulationViewer.java:492)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PAINT(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.ui.View.show(View.java:153)
at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.Simulator.start(Simulator.java:186)
at Environment.run(Environment.java:136)
at Environment.main(Environment.java:61)
```

This error does not occur every execution, let alone at the same point (which we think would be the case for normal errors, since we use a `RandomGenerator` for every 'random'). 
The code from our `Viewbuilder`:

```
 View.Builder viewBuilder = View.builder()
  .with(WarehouseRenderer.builder()
    .withMargin(VEHICLE_LENGTH))
  .with(AGVRenderer.builder()
    .withDifferentColorsForVehicles())
  .with(PDPModelRenderer.builder().withDestinationLines());
```

Comment: Can you verify whether this problem also occurs without using the UI?

Comment: It seems the problem does not occur without the UI.

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem is fixed in the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This NPE is fixed as of [RinSim v4.4.6](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/releases/tag/v4.4.6).